# jsf 1.2 UI Component tag backing bean

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, custom-component, jsf-1.2, backing-beans

I am using JSF 1.2 and I want to create a custom component using `ui:component` tag. I need to use this component in many places in my application, so I want this component to be highly reusable.

The problem is that for each use of this custom component I need a backing bean to store my information and act as action listener for certain events. I use this component in about 15 places within my application, and I also use this component more than once within a single page.

I don't want to create a custom JSF component (with UIComponent, renderer etc) and I don't know how to manage the backing data.

Is there any way I can specify a class, and the custom component creates an instance of the class each time I use it?

**Edit:**
Is it possible to extend an existing JSF component? (I use Richfaces implementation)

Any help or idea are welcome.